# How can I run these two methods at the same time C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get these two pictureboxes to increase in size then decrease in size at the same time using two different methods / while loops. How can I do this? The it works is that when the button is clicked the two picture boxes will increase in size till it reaches a given size then they will both decrease in size.

```
    private void bthGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        red();
        blue();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbxBlue.Width = 10;
        pbxRed.Width = 10;
    }

    public void red()
    {
        int width = 10;
        while (width < 156)
        {
            width++;
            pbxRed.Width = width;
            pbxRed.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        while (width > 10)
        {
            width--;
            pbxRed.Width = width;
            pbxRed.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void blue()
    {
        while (pbxBlue.Width < 156)
        {
            pbxBlue.Width++;
            pbxBlue.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        while (pbxBlue.Width > 10)
        {
            pbxBlue.Width--;
            pbxBlue.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered at all switching to WPF? Animations like you are trying to perform here are much easier to do (That `Thread.Sleep` on a UI thread is a real sign of "Code Smell").

Comment: I would say possible, but adding WPF makes everything else harder, and the animations and triggering and such really aren't all that clear.  If the only job for the UI is to do this, then it's probably a good bet. The UI using WPF is much much nicer, of course.  I do miss that half baked monstrosity.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
private void bthGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[]
    {
       new Task(red),
       new Task(blue),
    };

    foreach(var task in tasks)
       task.Start();

    new Task(red).Start();
    new Task(blue).Start();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to run the same task twice?  What about accessing the UI thread from a task thread? I think this is likely to crash

Comment: If you use this approach you will have to change the red/blue methods to Invoke the operations that change the size, which results than in having it all on one thread again/ not simultaneously!

Answer (score 0):

Every Control can only be updated by the Thread that created it, that said you just cannot  access the UI from two threads* simultaneously therefore you just can't achieve what you are trying to do in this way. If you wan't to create an animation why do you need two methods ?

And you should (as already mentioned in the Comments) get rid of the "Thread.Sleep" in the UI Thread, better use a Timer.

*There is a very dirty way to do this by setting the Property CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false. But this should NEVER be done as it leads to unexpected and untraceable bugs.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar serialized through the GUI thread does actually mean you delegate the operation to the ui thread which does mean it is always done on the ui thread

Comment: I re-read your answer and while it is a bit misleading, I now understand you're trying to say that only the UI thread can update the UI. This is correct. However, you make it sound like no two different threads can tell the UI thread to perform an update, which is wrong.